# Android - ожидание подключения Интернета

Tags: android, сеть

Есть метод, который проверяет есть ли подключение к интернету.

Как реализовать ожидание подключения к интернету (с выводом сообщения, что интернета нет)?

Дальнейший код не должен выполнятся пока не появится интернет.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону ресивера и интента изменения состояния подключения.

Вот [тут](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-internet-connection-status-network-change/) можно глянуть пример кода.

Answer (score 1):

Вот к примеру `BroadcastReceiver`

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static String TAG = NetworkChangeReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Network Connection is [" + isNetworkConnectedOrConnecting(context) + "]");
    }

    public  boolean isNetworkConnectedOrConnecting(Context context) {
        final ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
}
```

и метод который нужно прописать в атикивти и вызвать его:

```
 private void initBroadcastReceiver() {
        NetworkChangeReceiver receiver = new NetworkChangeReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
        registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
 }
```

Т.е. если есть подключение сети -  в лога будет Network Connection is [true]